# How to install Apache Atlas on a single EC2 node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I tried installing Apache Atlas on a single EC2 node but if fails to start:

```
wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/atlas/1.0.0/apache-atlas-1.0.0-sources.tar.gz

tar xvfz apache-atlas-1.0.0-sources.tar.gz
cd apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g"

mvn clean -DskipTests package -Pdist,embedded-hbase-solr

python atlas_start.py
/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 59: MANAGE_LOCAL_HBASE=${hbase.embedded}: bad substitution
/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 62: MANAGE_LOCAL_SOLR=${solr.embedded}: bad substitution
/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 65: MANAGE_EMBEDDED_CASSANDRA=${cassandra.embedded}: bad substitution
/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/conf/atlas-env.sh: line 68: MANAGE_LOCAL_ELASTICSEARCH=${elasticsearch.managed}: bad substitution
Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "atlas_start.py", line 163, in <module>
    returncode = main()
  File "atlas_start.py", line 73, in main
    mc.expandWebApp(atlas_home)
  File "/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/bin/atlas_config.py", line 160, in expandWebApp
    jar(atlasWarPath)
  File "/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/bin/atlas_config.py", line 213, in jar
    process = runProcess(commandline)
  File "/tmp/apache-atlas-sources-1.0.0/distro/src/bin/atlas_config.py", line 249, in runProcess
    p = subprocess.Popen(commandline, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderrFile, shell=shell)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1025, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How to install Apache Atlas on one AWS EC2?

Thanks.

Comment: You should figure out what file it thinks doesn't exist

Comment: @cricket_007 Does it work for you? Ever tried to install Atlas on 1 machine?

Comment: I generally test things in a VM locally before trying to run in AWS, but no, I have never manually installed Atlas

Answer (score 0):

I agree you should check the script. However, the notes are not very clear. You need to have configured it too. That means defining if you are using a pre-built ZK installation or not, but more importantly, Atlas by default uses HBase as its store. You MUST have HDFS available too, and change the config to point to HDFS Namenode (usually on port 9000).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if JAVA_HOME initialized or has correct value. Initializing with the valid value solved the issue for me.